# Running a PHP cronjob for more than 15 minutes

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, cron

I am participating to the Amazon Product Advertising API and they say in their terms of conditions, that I must update my data at least hourly. Ok no problem you think, easily mass-update the 800 objects in mysql db. But there's another point: I am allowed only to make 1 Amazon query per second, so I want to timeout each query, which will then last the php execution for about 15 minutes.
So this is a problem for me, because my provider configured a max execution time for php scripts of 20 seconds and I cannot change it.

So I thought of http-redirecting the php script to itself. 
Again no problem till now. But now's the problem: I want to htaccess-password-protect the script, my provider of cronjobs can handle htaccess pw protection. Without any protection this would be to unsafe, since there could be some heavy DB traffic if the script is abused.

Question: Is it possible to login to the htaccess login dialog with php, since there is no human beeing that can do the login process? Or do you have any other idea to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: There's definitely no way you can up the PHP timeout? Have you asked your hosting provider?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, they declined my request.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried running your own server using Amazon's EC2? You've got total control over the PHP settings then

Comment: I'd like to run the script on my own hosting. Spending money only to update my DB items? No, it's a quite small project.

Comment: Doesn't the url scheme `http://username:password@host.com/script` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adressing your initial problem: [execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

There are two places you can set this.

1. **configuration** - which you can't access or change apparently
2. **runtime** - I don't know any possibility to disallow changing the max execution time on runtime

In your script add this to the top. `set_time_limit` will set your execution time to unlimited, all other integer values are in seconds

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Adressing your second question : providing http auth credentials programmatically

This is just for the interested reader, I don't think (hope for you) you'll need this for that case

I'll send raw HTTP so this can be used for every kind of client and language which is able to open a tcp socket connection

My source: [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol)

```
<?php
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';

// computing authorization digest
$httpAuthDigest = base64_encode( "{$username}:{$password}" );

// connecting to the remote server
$fp = fsockopen( 'www.zappos.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 60 );
if (!$fp) {
    die( "{$errstr} ({$errno})\n" );
}

// send headers
fputs( $fp, "HEAD /womens-clothing HTTP/1.1\r\n" );
fputs( $fp, "Host: www.zappos.com\r\n" );
fputs( $fp, "Authorization: Basic {$httpAuthDigest}\r\n" );
fputs( $fp, "Connection: close\r\n" );
fputs( $fp, "\r\n" );

// receive result ( optional )
while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
}
fclose($fp);
```

This returned the most exciting response header I know :)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.17
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-ZFC-Metadata: KjYIExIJCgNuaWQSAjQ1EhYKBmxheW91dBIMdGhyZWVfY29sdW1uEg8KA3pjMRIIQ2xvdGhpbmc=
X-Powered-By: Ponies!
X-Varnish-TTL: 60m
X-Varnish: 248743314 248742997
X-Cache-Hits: 4
X-Varnish-Host: varnish04.zappos.net
X-Varnish-ID: drupal
X-Core-Value: 5. Pursue Growth and Learning
X-Recruiting: If you're reading this, maybe you should be working at Zappos instead.  Check out jobs.zappos.com
X-UUID: 9dc901f6-38ca-11e2-be29-00145e157f03
Cache-Control: max-age=3085
Date: Tue, 27 Nov 2012 19:50:38 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: Hi Michel, thank you so much for your answer. I am not reputated enough to give you +1, but thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. Not reputated enough? What a shame :) can't even accept the answer using the tick below the vote up/down buttons? Good luck with your store

Comment: Unfortunately I have to reopen this thread. The script is aborting in chrome abfter about 1 to 2 minutes. PhpInfo() shows max_execution_time = 0 (20 master level). I do not input data to the script via GET or POST.

Answer (score 1):

OP stated he was still getting a timeout after a specific time, although overwriting the configured `max_execution_time` to unlimited, which was working according to `phpinfo()`

Consider it to be bad practise to call a `worker script` via a browser.
This can cause uncontrollable states and causes other troubles just like those you're experiencing right now - asides from possible troubles this could cause when somebody else gets the URL into his hands.

Also - a hourly import is quite uncomfortable to do manually in a browser isn't it?

Your problem is, that not php stops execution because of a timeout, but the webserver.
You said you dont pass any GET or POST parameters. Just run it on php-cli on your command line

```
php yourscript.php
```

All output will be logged into console. if you want you can write it into a logfile like this

```
php yourscript.php > log.txt
```

This still doesn't do anything automatically.
On any unix you can easily set up a cronjob doing this job for you at a desired time and interval

e.g.

```
crontab -e
```

to edit your configured cronjobs

```
* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /yourpath/yourscript.php > ~/yourlog.txt 2>/dev/null
```

This would run every two hours and log your script output to `~/yourlog.txt`, redirect errors into `/dev/null`

Check this to find out how the schedule table works
http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

I also advice to move your script out of your webserver's `document root` so it is no longer accessible from the web.

Comment: Hi Michel again, thank you! I now solved it with a (kind of bad) workaround: Even with external cronjobs by cronjob.de it's beeing aborted after about 200 refreshed objects (-> A bit more than 3 minutes running). I now have the job started every 5 minutes and query 175 elements which are out of date from my the DB and sync them with amazon. If no object is out of date, the job will be finished immediately. So this is not ideal, but it works and I don't have to spend more hours on setting up the cronjob serverside. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution.